# getJSON will not work

Tags: jquery, json

Here is my code. What I want to do is log the data and be able to use the json data but it just won't work.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $.getJSON("http://removed_for_privacy.me/exercises.json", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(1); 
});
});
```

This does not log the data and it doesn't even run the alert(1). This is running off a server, any ideas?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: They are on the same server in the same folder

Comment: @user3381694 are you sure that exercises.json is valid JSON?

Comment: 1. is "removed_for_privacy.me" on the same domain? 2. What kind of page are you calling (aspx, php)? Does that page create a json object successfully?

Comment: You can remove all the `http://address` stuff and keep just the path relative to the current page then. Other than that, make sure you've included the jQuery library correctly. Then check the DevTools' Network tab to see if you're getting any 404's.

Comment: You may try; `$.getJSON(...).fail(function(err) { alert(err); })` in order to get more useful info

Comment: Do you have errors in you console?

Comment: ^ no, there are no errors. The console shows nothing (Chrome and FireFox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with `getJson` doesn't return errors, use regular ajax instead,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://removed_for_privacy.me/exercises.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( data ) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function( data ) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

or, use `.fail`

```
$.getJSON("http://removed_for_privacy.me/exercises.json", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(1); 
})
.fail(function(jqxhr){
   alert(jqxhr.responseText);
});
```

Comment: This worked, do you know why this works and the getJSON doesn't?

Comment: I mean it logged the data in the console ^ but getJSON doesn't even when I used the same info

Comment: @user3381694: You'll be logging it via the `fail()` handler, which would indicate your JSON isn't valid. Use http://jsonlint.com/ to see what's wrong.

Comment: You could use `console.log('error', data);` to easily differentiate between which handler was called.

Comment: JSON lint says the file is valid

Comment: It all works now, problem was my linking with my json file in the wrong place.